# Firebase Notification Listview

Tags: java, android, json, listview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully sent Firebase notifications using my own server to android app and I am listing the messages in a listview in a new activity on clicking the notification. My issue is if I click on one particular notification, all unread notification messages are getting displayed in listview

FirebaseMessageservice.java

```
private void sendPushNotification(JSONObject json) {
    //optionally we can display the json into log
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification JSON " + json.toString());
    try {
        //getting the json data
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");


        //parsing json data
        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        list.add(message);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        System.out.println(list);

        MyNotificationManager mNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        //if there is no image
        if(imageUrl.equals("null")){
            //displaying small notification
            mNotificationManager.showSmallNotification(title, message, intent);
        }else{
            //if there is an image
            //displaying a big notification
            mNotificationManager.showBigNotification(title, message, imageUrl, intent);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

> HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notification_list);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Output Screens

If i click on Hello Mom, It moves to next activity with listview but with both messages are getting displayed "1. Mom 2. Dad"

[image]

[image]

Comment: should the first method be called showNotification or sendPushNotication?

Answer (score 0):

`list.add(message);` is not ok because if the app is closed by the system (because the user opens another other app which needs more memory) you loose the data.

what you want to do is adding more info to the "intent" like

```
intent.setExtra(KEY, VALUE);
```

and in the activity you have to retrieve the intent used to launch it with

```
getIntent()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send the relevant data via intent.

```
intent.setExtra(KEY, VALUE);
```

then you must call it using `getIntent()` function.